# @Html.ValidationMessageFor crashes when I try to edit an item

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Why is my `@Html.ValidationMessageFo` not working? When I run the application, nothing happens and it allows everything to be entered. And it also crashes when I try to edit an item in my edit view, which is below. I have the following:

```
<div class="editor-label">
       @* @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Posted)*@
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Posted, Model.Posted = DateTime.Now)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sendinghome)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cartypes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cartypes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cartypes)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegNum)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegNum)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegNum)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Regprice)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Regprice)
    </div>
```

Comment: You should probably show more code. How's your model defined? Any data annotation attributes? And how's the controller?

Comment: Everything works fines what do u want to see? It is the validation that does not work? How is the controller effecting it? as the code runs and works fine only to when i edit

Comment: If everything works fine, what's the point of this question? I cannot answer your questions without seeing what is to validate. So how are your validation rules defined? And how is the controller handling the validity of your model?

Comment: This is thing there is nothing in my controller regarding validation this is all I have them Validation messages the tutorials that I have followed the music app one does not have any validation code in controller just these @Html.ValidationMessageFor and all works and when i start my own these messages dont work

Comment: It's not possible to diagnose what you've posted because there is nothing wrong with THAT code.  The problem is elsewhere.  Are you including the validation scripts on this view/layout?

Comment: Edit your post and add the code of the action method to which your form gets posted. Also you can add the definition of your model class.

Comment: @FredWilson The question says nothing about client side validation though.

Comment: True, an unwise assumption on my part.

Answer (score 35):

Here is how validation works.

Let's say you have the following model:

```
public class MyModel {
    [Required]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Note the [`Required`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) attribute, it is a data annotation attribute that specifies that `MyProperty` is a required field.

`MyModel` is used by the following view (*MyView.cshtml*):

```
@model MyNamespace.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController")) {
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyProperty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyProperty)

    <input type="submit" value="Click me">
}
```

Then, when this form gets posted to the `MyAction` action of `MyController`, the validation of your model will be performed. What you have to do is check whether your model is *valid* or not.
It can be done using the `ModelState.IsValid` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
         // save to db, for instance
         return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");
    }
    // model is not valid
    return View("MyView", model);
}
```

If the validation failed, the view will be rendered again using the different errors that are present in the `ModelState` object. Those errors will be used and displayed by the `ValidationMessageFor` helper.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, Bertrand explains it right, you could also use jquery validation too and eliminate the calls to the server validating on the browser. (asp.net mvc takes care of validating the rules on your model automatically)

Comment: Except that you *shouldn't* eliminate the server-side validation because you can't count on client-side validation ever.  Client-side validation is a nice-to-have enhancement, but only server-side validation can be trusted.