# ASP.NET core 2.2 Unhandled exception when creating a form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently creating a web application that takes in a new user, adds their information to a list, and then displays the users. When I follow the link to my form with validation (a form I have used many times before in other projects) I am getting an unhandled exception.

Here is the specific error code

```
    AspNetCore.Views_Home_RegisterNewUser.<ExecuteAsync>b__12_0() in RegisterNewUser.cshtml, line 15
```

To this point, I have double checked that the model is correct and has the correct validation. I have made sure the controller and action are correct.

Here is the page for the form

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RegisterNewUser";
}

<h1>RegisterNewUser</h1>

@model Lab20.Models.RegisterUser

@Html.ValidationSummary()

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ListAllUser" method="post" class="bg-dark">
    <div class="col-12">
        First Name: 
        <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="@Model.FirstName" placeholder="@Model.FirstName" class="col-5" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last Name" value="@Model.LastName" placeholder="@Model.LastName" class="col-5" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)

    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        Birthday: <input type="datetime" name="Birthday" value="@Model.Birthday" placeholder="@Model.Birthday" class="col-5" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Birthday)

    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        Email: <input type="text" name="Email" value="@Model.Email" placeholder="@Model.Email" class="col-5" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)

    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        Password: <input type="text" name="Password" value="@Model.Password" placeholder="@Model.Password" class="col-5" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        Favorite Color: <input type="text" name="FavoriteColor" value="@Model.FavoriteColor" placeholder="@Model.FavoriteColor" class="col-5" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FavoriteColor)

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
</form>
```

Here is the HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        List<RegisterUser> listOfUsers = new List<RegisterUser>() { };
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult RegisterNewUser()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult RegisterNewUser(RegisterUser newUser)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(newUser);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("AddNewUser", newUser);
            }
        }
        public IActionResult AddNewUser(RegisterUser user)
        {
            listOfUsers.Add(user);
            return View("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult ListAllUsers()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I would like my page to firstly, display, secondly, catch the validation I have added, and thirdly take the new user's information and display it in the ListAllUsers View.

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735277/html-validationmessagefor-not-working

Comment: It did not match my issue, thank you for the recommendation though

Answer (score 0):

`<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RegisterNewUser" method="post" class="bg-dark">
</form>`

your form post action will be in `RegisterNewUser` method, you're pointing it wrong in `ListAllUsers`.

hope, you get it

Answer (score 0):

You form is posing to the action `ListAlluser` in the controller `Home`. Now according to your code, you don't have an action method by that name.
The correct `asp-action` parameter should be `RegisterNewUser`. So the code becomes

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RegisterNewUser" method="post" class="bg-dark">
</form>
```